# maximum of ${\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}x_i^m} }\left({\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}x_i^{m - 1}} }\right)^{-1}$, ${a_i} > 0,{x_i} \ge 1, m \ge 1$

Tags: calculus, summation, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

I want to show that
(1) the value of the following formula increases as $m$ increases and
(2) the limit or the maximum value is equal to the maximum among $x_i$.

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

$$
f = \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}x_i^m} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}x_i^{m - 1}} }},{a_i} > 0,{x_i} \ge 1, m \ge 1
$$

**Proof of the second part**

Following @sku's suggestion: suppose $x_k$ is the maximum among $x_i$, then divide the numerator and denominator by $a_k x_k^{m-1}$, the problem can be simplified as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
{b_i} = \frac{{{a_i}}}{{{a_k}}} > 0,\\
{y_i} = \frac{{{x_i}}}{{{x_k}}} \in \left( {0,1} \right],y_i^{m - 1} = \frac{{x_i^{m - 1}}}{{x_k^{m - 1}}} \in \left( {0,1} \right],\\
{w_i} = {b_i}y_i^{m - 1} \in \left( {0,{b_i}} \right]
\end{array}
$$

The equlity holds when $i=k$. Now $f$ becomes:

$$
f = \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{b_i}y_i^{m - 1}{x_i}} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{b_i}y_i^{m - 1}} }} = \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{w_i}{x_i}} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{w_i}} }}
$$

Let $w_{i}^{\prime}=\frac{w_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_{j}}$, we get

$$
f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w^{'}_{i} x_i
$$

$f \le x_k$ because

$$
{x_k} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{w^{'}_i x_i}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {w_i^{'}} \left( {{x_k} - {x_i}} \right) \ge 0
$$
The equality holds when $w^{'}_k=1$ and $w^{'}_i=0,~\forall i \ne k$. This proves the second part.

**Proof of the first part**

Following a friend's suggestion: we can prove the first part by treating $f$ as a function of ${m}$ and then showing that $f^{'}({m})>0$.

Let $g=\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_j}y_j^{m-1}}$, then taking the derivative of $f({m})$ we get

$$
\begin{align}
{f^{'}}\left( {m} \right) &= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{{{a_j}y_j^{m-1}{x_j} \cdot \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}y_i^{m-1}\left( {\ln {y_j} - \ln {y_i}} \right)} }}{{{g^2}}}} \\
& = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{{a_i}{a_j}y_i^my_j^{m-1}}}{{{g^2}}}\left[ {{x_j}\left( {\ln {y_j} - \ln {y_i}} \right)} \right]} } \\
& = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{{a_i}{a_j}y_i^my_j^{m-1}}}{{{g^2}}}\left[ {{x_j}\left( {\ln \frac{{{x_j}}}{{{x_k}}} - \ln \frac{{{x_j}}}{{{x_k}}}} \right)} \right]} } \\
& = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{{a_i}{a_j}y_i^my_j^{m-1}}}{{{g^2}}}\left[ {{x_j}\left( {\ln {x_j} - \ln {x_i}} \right)} \right]} } 
\end{align}
$$

Let $0 \le \varepsilon  \le \frac{{{a_i}{a_j}y_i^my_j^{m - 1}}}{{{g^2}}}$, then we have

$$
\begin{align}
2{f^{'}}\left( m \right) &= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{{a_i}{a_j}y_i^my_j^{m - 1}}}{{{g^2}}}\left[ {{x_j}\left( {\ln {x_j} - \ln {x_i}} \right)} \right]} }  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{{a_i}{a_j}y_i^my_j^{m - 1}}}{{{g^2}}}\left[ {{x_i}\left( {\ln {x_i} - \ln {x_j}} \right)} \right]} } \\
 &\ge \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\varepsilon \left[ {{x_j}\left( {\ln {x_j} - \ln {x_i}} \right) + {x_i}\left( {\ln {x_i} - \ln {x_j}} \right)} \right]} } \\
 &\ge \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\varepsilon \left[ {\left( {{x_i} - {x_j}} \right)\left( {\ln {x_i} - \ln {x_j}} \right)} \right]} } 
\end{align}
$$

Because $\forall\, u, v \in \mathbb{N}$, ${x_u}\left( {\ln {x_u} - \ln {x_v}} \right) + {x_v}\left( {\ln {x_v} - \ln {x_u}} \right) = \left( {{x_u} - {x_v}} \right)\left( {\ln {x_u} - \ln {x_v}} \right) > 0
$, thus $f^{'}({m})>0$. This completes the proof for the first part.

There might be purely algebraic proofs (maybe related to the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)), but the above proof works for now.

Actually, using the second part, we can easily derive the second part. Since $f$ is monotonically increasing with $m$, the maximum of $f$ is achieved when $m \rightarrow \infty$ where $w_k=1$ and $w_i=0,\; \forall \, i \ne k$.

Comment: Suppose $x_k$ is the maximum among $x_i$. Dividing num and den by $a_k x_k^{m-1}$ and as $m$ goes to $\infty$ we will get left with $x_k$. Even if some numbers are equal it would result in same answer.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} w^{'}_{i} x_i$ is the dot product of $\bf w'$ and $\bf x$: keeping $\bf x$ firm, the product will increase when ...